# How can I automatically generate test cases for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

Is there any way to auto-generate simple test cases? I found myself spending time writing very simple tests that make sure all controllers and models are working fine. Here is an example of controller test case written with rspec:

```
machine = FactoryGirl.create(:machine, type: 1)
mac = FactoryGirl.create(:mac, machine_id: m1.id)
win = FactoryGirl.create(:win, machine_id: m4.id)
sign_in user
get :index
get :show, id: machine.id
get :report
```

I cannot find any tool today that can auto-generate such tests based on new written code. If really nothing exists, I may consider building a solution to this problem.

Comment: You could write a generator http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html

Comment: You are up against the common problem that Rails makes the most basic code (hit a page, hit a form, submit values, etc.) much easier than writing their matching tests. Stick with it, even if it's boring, so that when you need to add serious logic, the test framework is in place to help you. THEN the tests will be easier than the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cover basic functionality you could write a specific [generator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html).

You can also redefine standard scaffold templates (for example, by adding your own template to lib/templates/rspec/model/model_spec.rb - this will redefine model scaffolding).

But the real question is why to do so. Following TDD you should write the test and then create your code, not vice versa.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of TDD, I like to code then test. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

If a test were predictable enough to generate it wouldn't be worth writing. In your example, you don't assert anything. That's a very weak test, good only for raising code coverage. It would be much stronger if it asserted what should be on the page. You can't generate that. You also can't generate a scenario that traverses multiple pages in a meaningful way. (I think your example wants to be an rspec feature spec or a Cucumber scenario.)

It would make sense to write a generator that creates a skeleton that the developer could fill in with the meaningful parts that can't be generated, however.

Comment: For some applications, just having a 200 response is good enough to be confident that everything is good. These tests were actually super helpful, I didn't have to spend much time writing them and every time I make lots of changes, I would run rspec just to make sure I didn't break anything and then deploy. Hence, the need to have them automatically generated since they have low complexity and repetitive aspect.

Comment: I've done that too, for existing applications when I hadn't had time to write thorough tests yet. (It's hard to imagine an application that has no page content that would benefit from assertions.) But in my experience response-status-only tests only make sense when each test case is a single GET, and then you can write a single piece of code that reads a list of URLs to GET (or controller-action pairs to get in rspec, or whatever) and you don't need to generate as such.